# How to update java version to 1.6 or 1.7 in oracle 10g database

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

We are trying to execute some java code in oracle database, according some requirement. But we noticed that some methods are not supported by default java version in ORACLE 10g i.e. JAVA 1.4. So, we wants to know how to update java version to 1.6 or 1.7 in oracle 10g database.

Comment: are you seriously asking us how you can update to java 1.6,  while java 6 has been out of date for over a decade? Ö

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/stevenchan/updating-the-default-jdk-installed-in-oracleas-10g

Comment: @Stultuske Actually we having some old projects in which we have to implement some java functionalities. Can you just tell me how to  update java version to 1.6 or 1.7 or any latest on in oracle 10g database

Comment: 1. download a more recent jdk 2. build the application 3. solve any issues where the jdk's are not compatible 4. run it on a server/jre/... that supports the new version

Comment: @Stultuske That does not answer the question of "How to upgrade the version of java that is used internally in an Oracle 10g database".

Comment: @MT0 Yes you are right.

Comment: @StuPointerException The link you given is perfect, but it require CUSTOMER Support Identifier to access MY ORACLE SUPPORT, which I dont have.